# iOS VoiceOver/rotor: header navigation not going back to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

In the app I'm working on, there is one `UITableView` with section headers. The tableView is in a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. With VoiceOver on, and the rotor set to headings, I want to be able to navigate from one header to the next, back and forth, using the swipe up/down feature.

I have validated that the navigation bar title and the tableView section headers all have the accessibility trait of `.headers`.

What is currently working:

- swipe down, from the navigation bar's title to the first tableView section headers
- swipe up and down between sections to navigate between them.

What is not working:

- swipe up from the first section header to the navigation bar title.

There is another view controller in the app where it's working, so I know it's possible, but I can't figure out why the behaviours differ.

I tried:

- setting different accessibility properties to the navigationBar/item
- comparing the working and non-working view controllers with the Debug View Hierarchy (as far as I can tell, they have the same hierarchy and same accessibility attributes).
- Because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987105/ios-voiceover-focus-not-moving-beyond-navigation-bar), I also looked at how the viewControllers are presented, and it's the same thing.

Is there an aspect of it I'm overlooking?
**What elements/attributes have an impact on the rotor heading navigation?**

Comment: Some of your navigation terms are not specific. When you say "*going down*" or "*navigating up*", are you talking about the vertical up/down swipe gesture? If so, that gesture depends on your rotor setting but you didn't say what the rotor was set to when you swiped vertically.

Comment: There's also a difference between a "head**er**" and a "head**ing**". A "header" is a table term and refers to the row and column headers. In HTML, that would be a `<th>`. (I know you're not talking about HTML but I was just giving an example.) A "heading" is a section label. In HTML, that would be an `<h2>`. Unfortunately, iOS has a heading trait called UIAccessibilityTraitHead**er** (instead of "TraitHead**ing**") but the rotor setting (Setttings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Rotor) is called "Head**ings**". Anyway, are you trying to find a way to swipe vertically to a table head**er**?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will make sure to update my question to be more precise with my wording. You are right to point it out. (And I understand the html is just a reference, thank you for that) 
Basically you understood the question: I am talking about swipe up/down gestures to navigate between headings (UI elements with `.header` accessibility trait). 
The rotor on the device is set to "Headings".
I hope this is clearer?
I also found a possible explanation for the different behaviours between 2 seemingly identical view controllers, I'm testing out my theory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a `UIKit` bug. The difference between working and non-working view controllers is the presence or not of a first section without a header. The image below explains it better. In the picture, the arrows represent working navigation (how VoiceOver focus moves from one *headings* to the next with swipe up/down gestures).

[image: Diagram of view controller hierarchy with working and non-working navigation]

Upon further investigation, I saw that in the Settings app, the Mail section has the same issue. (Screenshot as a reference). If the VoiceOver focus is on "Allow mail to access", swipe up does not lead to the focus on "Mail" title in the navigation bar.

[image: Screen capture of the Mail section of the Settings app in iOS 16]

As far as I can tell, SwiftUI does not have the issue, so we'll see about rewriting the view with SwiftUI.

Comment: Interesting. I can see the behavior you describe. If my VO focus is on "Settings" in the upper left and my rotor is set to "Headings", swiping down **does** move the focus to "Mail" then "Allow Mail..." then "Preferred Language", etc. But swiping up will not get back to "Mail". Is there an Apple app where the first section does **not** have a heading so I can see the swipe up going back to the top heading?

Comment: Yes, the Camera section of the Settings app (Settings -> Camera). I can easily go from "Composition" to "Camera" by swiping up.

Comment: I agree. I see both examples working as you described. It's definitely an Apple bug that you should report.